# PHP Array Returning [object Object]. Tried existing answers results with no luck

Tags: php, array

I have tried multiple solutions that I have found around and none seem to be working. Can anyone give me any help? I want the result to return the ID's (`$user`) and currently it returns `[object Object]` with the code below. `$users` gives me all the sites user ID's and `$pageview` gets the number of times the page has been visited. If I change the return statement to `$test` I get all the values from `$pageview` correclty as they should be. The need for adding the key `'count'` as `$pageview` is so that I can sort the array by the value of `pageview` in order to order the values based on the most popular page. I know this isn't the most efficient way to do this and using a proper analytics system would be better but for this task I need a method like this.

```
            if($args == 'Popular'){
                $users = get_all_user_ids('');
                foreach($users as $user) {
                    $pageview = get_user_meta($user, 'page_visits', true);
                    $test[] = $pageview;

                    if ($pageview != 0) {
                        $popularid[$pageview]['count'] = $user;
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }
                    rsort($popularid);
                }
                return $popularid;
            }
```

The output is being encoded with `json_encode` after it has gone through this if statement and is then output onto the page in a JS function using `document.getElementById("cm-output").innerHtml`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the function of this line: `$pageviews = $pageview + $user;`

Comment: If you're getting an object have you tried var dumping it?

Comment: @TamilvananN That line adds the values together so that the if statement can check if anything has been added to the user ID, I realise I could just check if its equal to 0.

Comment: @Aravona I have tried var dumping it and it doesn't return anything. I should probably add that the information is being json_encoded after it gets the ID's and then is being output onto the page with .innerHtml

Comment: @M.F. Yess... You now checked based on 0. I think array str with key needs to be changed. Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try the below code,

```
$users = get_all_user_ids('');
$i=0; // initialization 
foreach($users as $user) {
    $pageview = get_user_meta($user, 'page_visits', true);
    if ($pageview != 0) {
        //$popularid[$pageview]['count'] = $user; // Err:  // Array won't be unique due to pageview might be same for multiple users
        // $popularid[$user] = $pageview; // Array will be unique based on user id
         $popularid[$i]['user'] = $user;
         $popularid[$i]['pageview'] = $pageview;
         $i++; // incrementor
    }
}
//rsort($popularid); // Sorts based on value
usort($popularid, function($a, $b) {
   return $a['pageview'] - $b['pageview'];
});
$userArr = array_column($popularid, 'user');
//return $popularid;
return $userArr;
```

**Update:**
Core PHP code example for `usort`

```
$array[] = array('pageview'=>4,'user'=>'abc');
$array[] = array('pageview'=>2,'user'=>'xyz');
$array[] = array('pageview'=>1,'user'=>'pqrs');
$array[] = array('pageview'=>3,'user'=>'ijk');

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['pageview'] - $b['pageview'];
});

$userArr = array_column($array, 'user'); // to get only the values from user key
print_r($userArr);
```

Comment: That does give me the results in the correct order which is the first step but I need the output to be the ID's set in $user rather than the values themselves in $pageview as I pass these ID's into another function to get the user avatars with the user ID's.

Comment: Do you want hight to low order? And it's based on page view(s) correct??

Comment: Correct, I need the highest value first and the lowest value last based on the value of $pageview but outputting the value of $user.

Comment: So, In the return array you don't want the page views. Only user id's in the desired order.

Comment: Yes exactly, the page views is purely to determine the order.

Comment: In which order you got it using this code. Can you post that?

Comment: Currently, if I output $users it will give `98,189,194,204,205,192,195,193,135,208,196,134,190,202,206,191,203` and that will correspond to this order for the $pageview `3,,,,,,,,,9,2,12,,,,,11`. When I try to sort them it sorts based on $user so that doesn't work and when I add a key it returns [object Object].

Comment: Okay. rsort removes the key. Lets try usort. Updated the code.Check now

Comment: This also returns `[object Object]`

Comment: In which place, you got this?

Comment: On my website page, it is the output that is shown after $popularid is passed through json_encode and output to the page through .innerHTML like I said in my post.

Comment: Check the print array before return

Comment: Not sure how to get that to get it to print, think I need an extension which I cant add on this computer. Also with the format you have given me with the `$popularid[$i]['user'] = $user; $popularid[$i]['pageview'] = $pageview;` returns only 1 value, the latest, instead of all of the values that are valid.

Comment: Sorry man, In that code. I have initiated `$i` as 0 but forgot to put incrementor on this. Please add & check

Comment: Been working on something else. Now it just has [object Object] 5 times instead of once.

Comment: Updated `usort` working example in Core PHP. Check it.

Comment: Still just prints out `[object Object`] if I try to use that format with it

Comment: I imagine that what it's doing is trying to print both the pageview and the user when its passed through to the javascript hence `[object Object]` but thats just a guess.

Comment: Use `array_column` to filter only the desired key-value from the array. Check the updated code.

Comment: Thats the one! Thank you so much, I appreciate your patience in figuring it out with me.